# Drawing a chemical molecule structure - chemfig - [ ] in centering

Tags: chemfig

I would like the [ ] to be in the center and I'm not succeeding.

```
\chemfig{HO-[@{left,0.25}]CH_{2}CH_{2}O-[@{right,0.25}]OH}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 10pt, depth = 10pt, indice = n]{left}{right}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Ah ☺️ I am glad to see your comment. Thank you also to @Markus G.

Answer (score 2):

Probabily that you have forgotten the 2nd size parameter (see `0.8`) after `@{left,0.5}` (for example), and you will have the square brackets to be in the center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{HO-[@{left,0.5},0.8]CH_{2}CH_{2}O-[@{right,0.5},0.8]OH}
\polymerdelim[height=10pt, depth=10pt, indice=\!n, delimiters={[]}]{left}{right}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I point out (as a chemist) that the horizontal position of the brackets is not a question of aesthetics, but carries chemical information as well. Therefore, the position should be at the same position for both, seeing as the bond is partially part of the repeating unit and partially that of the end groups. The most symmetrical solution would be using 0.5 for both, but that is then up to you.

Comment: @MarkusG. Very kind Markus, I am not a chemist, sorry. I have understand that the OP would to have the symmetrical brackets. However I am glady if you would to change my code or I can freely delete my answer. My regards.

Comment: No, definitely do not delete. Your answer was perfectly fine, I just pointed out this detail because some people can be quite nitpicky about it. It was meant more as an additional information than as criticism. (I did however adjust your answer to reflect this, because you said you didn't mind.)

Comment: @MarkusG. Don't worry especially with me :-). Thank you very much for your editing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and grateful for the help!